# How to draw thin borders / walls on a Godot tile map?

Tags: tilemap, godot

I'm trying to make a map of a home consisting of rooms with thin walls for a simple top-view game. I'm struggling to implement thin walls with the tile set.

Let me explain what I mean: if two cells are neighbours, but there is a border between them (a wall or a closed door), then you cannot move from one to other, and if there is an open door, then you can pass.

There will be several options for walls and doors, so I think it is impractical to draw each set in the tile set. Is it possible to just dynamically add walls and doors to empty cells through the code?

For a test, I made a simple situation with one cell and one type of wall and a door. I plan to rotate and position the sprite in the right direction depending on the position of the cell. I just don't understand how to do it, and how the built-in path search will work.

The problem is also that when I try to draw something manually, the walls are placed in the middle and I can't find where to move and rotate them. Is it possible to put 2, 3 or 4 walls on one cell in this way?

I use Godot 4.0.beta.10.mono

[image: Example tile map]

Comment: You might want to consider [thinking about your map on the dual grid](https://twitter.com/OskSta/status/1448248658865049605), so corners of rooms are the centers of tiles. It cuts down on the number of tiles you need to support different shapes.

Comment: Please edit to indicate which version of Godot you're using. Some of the 3.x navigation API is deprecated & not available in 4.x.

Comment: I use Godot 4.0 c#